# How to extend Code igniter cache class Redis class

Tags: codeigniter, caching, redis

I am using redis for caching in one of my assignment. I am using CI default redis library for this purpose.

Now the issue with library is that it has some specific set of method which are used to set, get, delete , increment and decrement the redis keys & values.

I want to additional function of redis like lpush, rpush,lrem, lrange etc.
So to achieve this , i am trying to extend default CI redis class. which i am putting in application/libraries/driver/cache_redis_extended.php.
my code for this class is as follow.

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Cache_redis_extended extends CI_Cache_redis
{

    function __construct()
    {
         parent::self;
    }

    public function rpush($list, $data)
    {
        $push = $this->_redis->multi(Redis::PIPELINE);      
        return $push->rpush($list, json_encode($data));
    }
    
    public function lrem($list, $data)
    {
        if((is_string($data) && (is_object(json_decode($data)) ||      is_array(json_decode($data))))) {
            $data = $data;
        }else{
            json_encode($data);
        }
        return $this->_redis->lrem($list,-1, $data);
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        if ($this->_redis)
        {
            $this->_redis->close();
        }
    }
    
}
```

and in my model I am loading this class as follows

```
 $CI->load->driver('cache', array('adapter' => 'redis'));
```

But I get this error:

**Unable to load the requested class: cache_redis_extended**

Any help is appreciated for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see your driver name is not started with Capitalized , so
it can be possible the cause of your issue.

Because according to codeigniter the naming rule of a class as follows

Naming Conventions

1. File names must be capitalized. For example: Myclass.php
2. Class declarations must be capitalized. For example: class Myclass
3. Class names and file names must match.

change your file name 
from **cache_redis_extended.php**
to **Cache_redis_extended.php**

I hope it will be helpful for you.